# Boto3 cannot find aws credentials on pycharm when using remote interpreter

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, boto3

I'm using a remote interpreter on PyCharm (docker container) and need to connect to AWS. My credentials work fine on the cli, even with the aws toolkit, but `boto3` cannot find them. How do I set it up properly?

Comment: does the remote have aws credentials? Probably not.

Comment: Either mount your ~/.aws inside of the container, or export the credentials as env variables for the container (`docker -e`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker container does not have access to your aws credentials from the host machine. There are several ways to solve this, the easiest being passing your aws access key and secret key as environment variables for the Docker container. For example:

To your `Dockerfile` you can add the following:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
```

Other ways might be to have an [`.env`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) file if you are using `docker-compose` or mounting `~/.aws` folder from the host machine as a volume inside the Docker container.

Keep in mind that these solutions work for local development using Docker. Sharing your credentials is not recommended from a security perspective, moreover pushing them to a version control repository is a really bad idea.

In order to make it more secure, you may want to create a role for your application in AWS and use [`assume-role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) to get temporary AWS credentials for that role, which might be passed to the Docker container.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks a lot!